# Flutter : text with TextAlign justify is cutting off inside a word

Tags: flutter, text, widget, word-wrap

inside the body of my current page, I just have a simple ListView containing the following text widget :

```dart
new Text(
  "By signing up you confirm that you have read and agree to the :",
  textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
  textScaleFactor: 1.0,
  style: TextStyle(
    fontSize: 14.0,
    fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
    fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
  ),
  maxLines: 2,
  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
  softWrap: true,
),
```

I would like my text to wrap, but its breaking in the middle of the word "agree", you can see a screen of the result below (the text under the signup button) :

[image: wordwrap-screenshot]

**[EDIT]**
I even tried to simplify my code by removing almost every non mandatory properties like following :
[image]

It render exatly the same
So please, where am I wrong ?

Thanks for your help.
Michel

Comment: check the softWrap property. By setting it true, the line breaks between words

Comment: as describe above the softWrap is already set to true, but that occure no changes on the cutt off behavior

Comment: it should be set to false

Comment: Sorry, set softWrap to true or false is the same